# Is there alternative way to print out buttons without using v-for

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have an delete option in my project, now I want to create a confirmation modal, but I had a problem with button printing. There is an issue, that quantity of this buttons equals of task quantity.[Screenshot of my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upta8.png) [Screenshot of my confirmation modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAjkq.png)

The point is that I want to display only one confirmation button to the task I want to delete.

```
<div v-for="(task, index) in tasks" :key="index">
  <div class="bg-gray-700 px-4 py-3 sm:px-6 sm:flex sm:flex-row-reverse">
    <button @click="removeTask(task)" type="button" class="w-full inline-flex justify-center rounded-md border border-transparent shadow-sm px-4 py-2 bg-blue-600 text-base font-medium text-white hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-blue-500 sm:ml-3 sm:w-auto sm:text-sm">
      Yes
    </button>
    <button @click="closeDeleteModal" type="button" class="mt-3 w-full inline-flex justify-center rounded-md shadow-sm px-4 py-2 bg-red-600 text-base font-medium text-white hover:bg-red-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-gray-500 sm:mt-0 sm:w-auto sm:text-sm">
       No
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

My delete method:

```
removeTask(task) {
  window.emitter.emit('changeLoaderStatus', true)
  axios.delete(window.location.origin + '/api/removeTask/' + task.id, this.taskData).then(response => {
      // Если задача успешно удалена, удаляем её из списка задач
      const index = this.tasks.findIndex(t => t.id === task.id);
      this.isAlertVisible = true;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.isAlertVisible = false;
      }, 3000);
      if (index !== -1) {
        this.tasks.splice(index, 1);
      }
      window.emitter.emit('changeLoaderStatus', false)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error deleting task:', error);
      window.emitter.emit('changeLoaderStatus', false)
    });
},
```

Delete modal:

```
<!-- Delete modal -->
      <div v-if="isDeleteModalOpen" class="fixed inset-0 z-10 overflow-y-auto" id="deleteModel" aria-labelledby="deleteModelLabel" role="dialog" aria-modal="true">
        <div class="flex items-end justify-center min-h-screen pt-4 px-4 text-center sm:block sm:p-0">
          <div class="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-500 bg-opacity-75 transition-opacity" aria-hidden="true"></div>
          <span class="hidden sm:inline-block sm:align-middle sm:h-screen" aria-hidden="true">&#8203;</span>
          <div class="inline-block align-bottom bg-gray-700 rounded-lg text-left overflow-hidden shadow-xl transform transition-all sm:my-8 sm:align-middle sm:max-w-lg sm:w-full">
            <div class="bg-gray-800 px-4 pt-5 pb-4 sm:p-6 sm:pb-4">
              <div class="sm:flex sm:items-start">
           
                <div class="mt-3 text-center sm:mt-0 sm:ml-4 sm:text-left">
                  <h3 class="text-lg leading-6 font-medium text-white" id="deleteModelLabel">
                    Are u sure that u want to delete task?
                  </h3>
                
                  
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="bg-gray-700 px-4 py-3 sm:px-6 sm:flex sm:flex-row-reverse">
              <button @click="removeTask(task)" type="button" class="inline-flex justify-center rounded-md border border-transparent shadow-sm px-4 py-2 bg-blue-600 text-base font-medium text-white hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-blue-500 sm:ml-3 sm:w-auto sm:text-sm">
                Yes
              </button>
              <button @click="closeDeleteModal" type="button" class="mt-3  inline-flex justify-center rounded-md shadow-sm px-4 py-2 bg-red-600 text-base font-medium text-white hover:bg-red-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-gray-500 sm:mt-0 sm:w-auto sm:text-sm">
                No
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

There is part of a my script:

```
<script>
    import { onMounted } from 'vue'
    import { initFlowbite } from 'flowbite'
    import { ref } from 'vue';
    import axios from 'axios';
  
    export default {
      name: 'ExampleComponent',
      setup() {
  
        onMounted(() => {
        initFlowbite();
        })
  
        const isDeleteModalOpen = ref(false);
  
        const openDeleteModal = () => {
          isDeleteModalOpen.value = true;
        }

        return {
          isDeleteModalOpen,
        };
      },
      data() {
        return {
          isAlertVisible: false,
          editMode: false,
          groupData: {
            groupname: 'main',
            id: '',
          },
          taskData: {
            id: '',
            title: '',
            date: '',
            time: '',
            status: 0,
            detail: '',
          },
          taskErrors: {
            title: false,
            date: false,
            time: false,
          },
          tasks: {},
          groups: [],
        }
      },
   
      methods: {
  
        removeTask(task) {
          window.emitter.emit('changeLoaderStatus', true)
      axios.delete(window.location.origin + '/api/removeTask/' + task.id, this.taskData).then(response => {
          
          const index = this.tasks.findIndex(t => t.id === task.id);
          this.isAlertVisible = true;
          setTimeout(() => {
          this.isAlertVisible = false;
        }, 3000);
          if (index !== -1) {
              this.tasks.splice(index, 1);
          }
          window.emitter.emit('changeLoaderStatus', false)
      })
      .catch(error => {
          console.error('Error deleting task:', error);
          window.emitter.emit('changeLoaderStatus', false)
      });
  },
        openDeleteModal(){
          this.isDeleteModalOpen = true;
        },
  
        closeDeleteModal(){
          this.isDeleteModalOpen = false;
        },
      }
    }
  </script>
```

Delete button to call methode with modal:

```
<button @click="openDeleteModal" class="transition-all duration-200 bg-red-600 hover:bg-red-700 text-white font-bold py-1 mr-2 px-3 rounded float-end">Delete</button>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing some context but if you don't want to render multiple buttons then remove the div with the `v-for`.   It seems the solution is quite simple.  Is there something else you _do_ need the `v-for` for?

Comment: @yoduh If I'm remove the div with v-for, there is an error, when i am trying to delete task. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

Comment: The modal needs to know what task it's working with. `v-for` doesn't help you with this, so still leave it removed.  Assuming the modal is a separate component, you should be passing in the task, or at least the task id, as a [prop](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#passing-props).  Something like `<modal :task="modalTask">` and you set `modalTask` when clicking one of the action buttons which will also open the modal.

Comment: It's not clear how your modal and the rest of your page code works together, so you may need to adjust this logic, but the core idea is the modal should know which task opened it.  If you need further help, edit your question to include the relevant code showing how the modal is opened and how it's rendered, then more specific advice can be given.

Comment: @yoduh I added more information about my code, thanks for being willing to help me, I just started learning Laravel and Vue, so maybe I'm asking stupid questions :)

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but basically what you want is 1. click on the delete button on the task you want to delete(photo 1). 2. When delete button is clicked, open modal with info of the tasks plus the confirm button and cancel button. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

First you need remove the v-for in deleteModal, then add a params task for  function openDeleteModal (you can get task form v-for), second add currentTask: null in function data, and set the currentTask in function openDeleteModal, now you will always known which task you are dealing without using v-for.

```js
    <button @click="openDeleteModal(task)" class="transition-all duration-200 bg-red-600 hover:bg-red-700 text-white font-bold py-1 mr-2 px-3 rounded float-end">Delete</button>
    
    ...

data() {
    return {
      isAlertVisible: false,
      editMode: false,
      groupData: {
        groupname: 'main',
        id: '',
      },
      taskData: {
        id: '',
        title: '',
        date: '',
        time: '',
        status: 0,
        detail: '',
      },
      taskErrors: {
        title: false,
        date: false,
        time: false,
      },
      tasks: {},
      groups: [],
      currentTask: null
    }
  },

  methods: {
    removeTask() {
      const task = this.currentTask
      window.emitter.emit('changeLoaderStatus', true)
      axios.delete(window.location.origin + '/api/removeTask/' + task.id, this.taskData).then(response => {

          const index = this.tasks.findIndex(t => t.id === task.id);
          this.isAlertVisible = true;
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.isAlertVisible = false;
          }, 3000);
          if (index !== -1) {
            this.tasks.splice(index, 1);
          }
          window.emitter.emit('changeLoaderStatus', false)
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Error deleting task:', error);
          window.emitter.emit('changeLoaderStatus', false)
        });
    },
    openDeleteModal(task) {
      this.isDeleteModalOpen = true;
      this.currentTask = task
    },

    closeDeleteModal() {
      this.isDeleteModalOpen = false;
    },
  }
}
```